# How can I install windows 8 on a laptop with inbuilt Linux(Ubuntu) in it

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a new Dell laptop which has inbuilt Ubuntu OS in it, I would like to install windows 8 alongside with Ubuntu without actually removing it.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It will be rather complicated for a beginner. Installing only Windows and then Ubuntu besides it would be easier, you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to partition the disc. I recommend using a tool like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) to partition your disc.

What you will need to do is boot from the Parted Magic live cd and choose the "Partition Editor" tool which is GParted, then resize your ubuntu partition to free up some space on your disc and then create a new NTFS partition.(you might have to juggle some partitions around to make enough room for windows 8)

You then need to reboot into windows 8 and select the partition you want to install it to.

Note:

- Windows 8 might not detect any other partitions.
- Windows 8 may not recognise ubuntu as another operating system.(it may be easier to backup everything, wipe your hard disk and install windows 8 first, and then reinstall Ubuntu).

Warning: 
Playing with partitions is risky, do take a backup of all your data before you begin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an empty partition

Boot your machine from the windows 8 disk

Install it on the empty partition